# traversing a BPEL array

Tags: soa, bpel

I need to traverse an array (input to BPEL) in java embed activity and need to generate a response (output variable) of BPEL process.

I am using Jdeveloper and SOA 11g

following is my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/BPELInpuandOutPutArray_jws/Project1/BPEL_input_output_array" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <element name="process">
            <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                        <element name="simpleinput" type="string"/>
                        <element name="arrayofObjects" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                              <complexType>
                                    <sequence>
                                          <element name="input1" type="string"/>
                                          <element name="input2" type="string"/>
                                    </sequence>
                              </complexType>
                        </element>
                  </sequence>
            </complexType>
      </element>
      <element name="processResponse">
            <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                        <element name="arrayofObjectsoutput" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                              <complexType>
                                    <sequence>
                                          <element name="output1" type="string"/>
                                          <element name="output2" type="string"/>
                                    </sequence>
                              </complexType>
                        </element>
                  </sequence>
            </complexType>
      </element>
</schema>
```

so far I am able to manage for traversing in input array

```
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement e1=
(oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement)getVariableData("inputVariable","payload","/client:process/client:arrayofObjects[1]/client:input1"); 

System.out.println(e1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

But my business requirement is to based on some logic set the values in output array.
for this I used following sample code.

```
for(int i=1; i < 4 ;i++) 
{ 
setVariableData("outputVariable","payload","/client:processResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput['i']/client:output1",i);
setVariableData("outputVariable","payload","/client:processResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput['i']/client:output2",i);
}
```

My feeling is array would be created of length 3 and value will be settes(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) but at the output value is only (3,3) .
please tell me how can i achieve the same.

sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for an XQuery?

Comment: My requirement is a BPEL process that has to return  a array of objects. how we will create that aray in my java embed activity. and return it. as I have pasted my xsd also in which we can see the output variable is arrayofObjectsoutput. will you please tell me how can i do that(so far i tried and able to traverse input array only)

Comment: This question is, again, vendor-specific, so please add a note about which product/tooling you use. Besides of that, in most cases it is considered a bad smell if BPELJ activities are used. The better approach would be to either use <assign> activities or refactor the business logic into a service.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: OK next time I will take care of all the things, @vanto will you please provide any sample process that is using assign activity for adding element in array, as i tried with copylist, appenlist function but this is not working.I have modified the tools and versions what i have used in question. thkns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it for a similar situation was to use a transformation to create the first element and then use the `bpelx:insertAfter` to insert additional array elements and then set them.

```
<assign name="Assign_2">
      <bpelx:insertAfter>
        <bpelx:from variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                    query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput"/>
        <bpelx:to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                  query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput"/>
      </bpelx:insertAfter>
      <copy>
        <from expression="'MyOutput1-Index2'"/>
        <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
            query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput[2]/client:output1"/>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from expression="'MyOutput2-Index2'"/>
        <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
            query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput[2]/client:output2"/>
      </copy>
</assign>
```

Comment: Hi I did the same and got the result also, but one doubt I have that when using bpelx:insertAfter>
        <bpelx:from variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                    query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput"/>
        <bpelx:to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                  query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput"/>
      </bpelx:insertAfter>
this piece of code copy whole array in iteself and length of array grows exponentially..  can you tell me significance of this line.

Comment: Ok, to prevent exponential growth, use this instead:

 <bpelx:from variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                    query="/client:ArrayManipulationProcessResponse/client:arrayofObjectsoutput[1]"/>

Answer (score 1):

If proprietary extensions do not work, you can try the standard BPEL approach and use an XSLT script to iteratively construct a result document.

An example is given in the [BPEL 2.0 specification, pp 65](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/wsbpel-v2.0.pdf), look for *Iterative document construction*.

Basically, the list and the element to add is passed (via the doXSLTransform XPath function) to an XSLT script, which copies the element to add to the list and returns the new document. This is then assigned to a variable.

Comment: Hi Vanto, thks for sharing the link. but I am not able to make it properly can you share me something else with simple example..

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example handy. You may check out the example at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ode/branches/ode-1.3.5.x/bpel-test/src/test/resources/bpel/2.0/TestXslTransform -- it does not append to an array, but it shows how to use XSL in BPEL. So together with the example in the BPEL spec, you should be able to come to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is no need to write custom Java code for such a simple task. The following code (BPEL2.0) does the job of copying the values.`<assign name="Copy values">
      <extensionAssignOperation>
          <bpelx:copyList>
               <bpelx:from>$inputVariable.payload/ns1:arrayofObjects</bpelx:from>
               <bpelx:to>$outputVariable.payload/ns1:arrayofObjectsoutput</bpelx:to>
           </bpelx:copyList>
      </extensionAssignOperation>
</assign>`

Comment: Thanks, But my requirement is creating an array based on some business logic.will you please make it more clear how can I achieve the same. say I have a class Officer(Value Objects) I will create 5 instance of this class and return it back from BPEL process. then I have to use  Array for returning it. In my xsd I have simulated the same with arrayofObjectsoutput element. please suggest me something.