# Bpel arrays transformation foreach

Tags: soa, bpel

I have a bpel process which receive an array and output another one.

The thing is, I need to get the first one elements, populate the second one and add some for elements in the second one.

My first one array is from this kind of object:

```
<xsd:complexType name="comment_A">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="picture" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="hour" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="bus-line" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="bus-number" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="rate" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

My second one:

```
<xsd:complexType name="comment_B">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="picture" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="hour" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="bus-line" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="bus-number" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="rate" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="type-comment" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="liked-number" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

So first, I tried iterate over the first array to populate the second one with properties which both have in common. I tried use forEach element.

My code seems like this:

```
<forEach parallel="yes" counterName="c" name="forEachComment">
  <startCounterValue>1</startCounterValue>
  <finalCounterValue>count($comments.VwCommentCollection/ns3:VwComment)</finalCounterValue>
  <scope name="Scope1">
    <assign name="assignResult">
      <extensionAssignOperation>
        <bpelx:copyList>
          <bpelx:from>$comments.VwCommentCollection[$c]</bpelx:from>
          <bpelx:to>$outputVariable.payload</bpelx:to>
        </bpelx:copyList>
      </extensionAssignOperation>
      <copy>
        <from>$comments.VwCommentCollection[$c]/ns3:VwComment/ns3:id</from>
        <to>$outputVariable.payload/ns2:comment/ns2:id</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
  </scope>
</forEach>
```

I tried do this first just with id element for a test, however when the comment_A array has size greater than 1, I receive an exception

$comment is my variable which comment_A array

Comment: What exception do you get? Also, if you're using a parallel foreach and don't use something like an atomic or isolated scope, it is likely that changes are overwritten. Depends on the implementation.

Comment: I received ORAMED-03303 before my foreach method. Do you know how can I debug this? I will try your isolate scope suggestion also

Comment: @vanto, according what I am understanding, my main problem is: $comments.VwCommentCollection/ns3:VwComment[$c]/ns3:id return id in for each. How can I push an object in my output array? I am trying set that value in $outputVariable.payload/ns2:comment[$c]/ns2:id however, I don't know if I need to initialize my $outputVariable.payload/ns2:comment with my its size or what

Comment: Now, my problem is just how to put an object in my output array. I created a temp variable and put things like $comments.VwCommentCollection/ns3:VwComment[$c]/ns3:id inside, so, I need to push this in my service's output variable

Comment: If you use oracle, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864666/traversing-a-bpel-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution following this Brazilian blog: http://blog.iprocess.com.br/2012/09/oracle-soa-suite-11g-uso-da-atividade-assign-no-bpel/

I used append opperation inside BPEL